# Perform operations on DOMParser object using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to set tabindex to all td present in below table using jQuery.

I can do this with following code, if the table is in dom.
But what if table is not still present in DOM?
Is it still in JavaScript variable?

So my question is about jQuery selector.
Given "table tr td", then could find it on DOM.

But how can I use my DOMParser object in jQuery selector so I will try to find table tag in my defined DOM object, not on document global object.

Please let me know if you have any answer on this.

```
$("table tr td").each(function (i) { $(this).attr('tabindex', 0); });
```

Any working on example on table manipulation would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
var xmlString = "<table id='tableabc' border='1' style='width:50%'> <tr> <th>Firstname</th> <th>Lastname</th> <th>Age</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Jill</td> <td>Smith</td> <td>50</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Eve</td> <td>Jackson</td> <td>94</td> </tr> </table>";

var parser = new DOMParser(); 

var doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
```

rest of the things how to use I am not sure on this.

Comment: jquery has [parseHTML](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/), this would mean to replace DOMParser but it will do your end goal I guess

Comment: Your question is unclear... Particularly this sentence: *«But how can I use my DOMParser...»* I tryed to improve it, but what you try to achieve is a mystery to me. Please  edit it.

Comment: i want to set tabindex to all td in a table using jquery for html content which is not yet on document.

Comment: Created JSFiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/8wxmmjjk/2/ in the link the table present on document already. But i want to apply tabindex on the html content which in present in a javascript variable not on document.  After setting tabindex then i will add this html on document.

Comment: You can't just sett the same tabindex to all `td`. This is useless. It will end like no tabindex at all. This is still unclear.

Comment: it is not more complicated to understand actually, the above jsfiddle link i have added in above comment. I have to achieve the same thing but here in this case my html table is in javascript variable. How to perform jquery operation on that variable, and not on document simple.

Comment: hey folks, any answers on this ?

Comment: hey guys, my query is resolved with my try. @LouysPatriceBessette thanks for helping. Thanks guys. Closing this off. [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/nsjttcvq/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var htmlstring = "<table id='table47' border='1' style='width:50%'> <tr> <th>Firstname</th> <th>Lastname</th> <th>Funny</th> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>N</td> <td>No</td> </tr> <tr> <td>A</td> <td>P</td> <td>Yes</td> </tr> </table>";

var $jQueryObject = $($.parseHTML(htmlstring));

$jQueryObject.each(function(){      
    var tdObj = $(this).find("td");
    var thObj = $(this).find("th");
    thObj.attr('tabindex', 7);
    tdObj.attr('tabindex', 8);
});

console.log($jQueryObject);
$("#divForParsedTable").html($jQueryObject);
```

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette : HTML was stored in string and i want to set some attributes to those html which was stored in string variable using jquery. 

I was not sure on how to select the html in a jquery selector to do the operation. Now answer found using parseHTML(string).  Thanks once again.

Comment: note that you could have done exactly the same with your original parsed document from DOMParser : just wrap the returned document in an jquery object and do the navigation from there : `$doc = $(new DOMParser().parseFromString('<a>Hello</a>', 'text/html')); $doc.find('a').attr('href', 'home');`